# How to Import 3D model into project from the server?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, backend

How can I import a 3D model into the game from some remote source (server/folder)?

So that, instead of keeping all the characters in the game project I could send some sort of request and receive a 3D model, and then place it into the scene?

I'm very new to the backend, so would really appreciate any description of how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use express js to serve files, its easy

Install it https://expressjs.com/en/starter/installing.html

FAQ Serving static files https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/serve-static.html

server.js

```
var express = require('express')
var path = require('path')
var serveStatic = require('serve-static')

var app = express()

app.get('/available', function(req, res){
   models = ['test', 'test2']
   res.json(models)
})

app.use(serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, 'models')))

app.listen(3000)
```

Run server with command node server.js
Put some files in models folder.
Now if you go to localhost:3000/available you will receive json with available models.
You project directory should have this structure 
Create models folder and put some files in it.

- node_modules
- package-lock.json
- package.json
- models
- server.js

Run server. node serve.js
Now open browser localhost:3000/model.

You need to have file with name model in models folder.

So the idea is to first go to localhost:3000/available and get a list of available models. Then download each of them if you want so.

This is very simple solution to you problem, but you can start from here.

Comment: Thank you very much! Will try this way :)